# How to remove "amplify-authenticator is not a known element" in Angular 11 and '@aws-amplify/ui-angular'

Tags: angular, aws-amplify

Looked around for an answer online and didn't see anything. Possibly because this wasn't that difficult to diagnose and fix, but thought I would post this so that it might save someone else a few minutes of time.

I faced an issue with using AWS Amplify's Authenticator component. Following the basic set up here -> https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/angular

Once I add the Amplify Angular UI Components to my app.component.html, my IDE (VS Code) complains that it cannot recognize the UI components. Nothing in the docs on how to address this.

Answer (score -1):

The reason that the IDE complains is that these are web components, so you need to add the CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA to your module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AmplifyUIAngularModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA], // <---this right here
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```